# Why is mat-form-field not working even after importing dependencies?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a little angular project where I use some Angular Material elements. Instead of having the old, lame html input field, I wanted to implement the cool Material one. But it is not working. I am using already some Angular Material elements like the Material Button successfully.

I checked existing posts but did not found a solution for this problem. I hope some of you can enlighten me in this case.

This is my code in the html:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Ex. Pizza" value="Sushi">
</mat-form-field>
```

Thats the result:

[image]

Note that there is also no `mat-label` showing.

app.module.ts:

[image]

Who can tell me what went wrong? Thanks for every help!

Comment: Add import for `MatInputModule`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add import for MatInputModule.